# 'Have" in Present Progressive

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

So I thought about phrase **"I'm 17 years old and I'm already having existential crisis"** - is it correct to use **"I'm already having"** on the scale of 17 years? Because it is a pretty long period of time.

If talking about existential crisis, then it's implied that I had it a week ago, I have it today, may be I'm having it at the moment (like a panic attack) and I will have it in the nearest future.

Comment: Correct? Yes. Unusual? No. Expect it to last for years.

Comment: Note that you're missing an article in "having **an** existential crisis". This question is better asked on our sister site, [ELL.se], I've voted to migrate it there. By the way, only people who have lived a short period of time believe 17 years is a long period of time.

Comment: Is it "an existential crisis" or "existential crises"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your sentence is perfect the way it is.  It's fine to use "already having" even though you are only 17 because this accurately describes your *experience*, and includes the nuance that you think 17 is not the right age for an existential crisis.

It's a little unclear to me whether you think 17 is too *old* or too *young* for this -- it seems like you think 17 is too old?  But this is just normal ambiguity and not due to any grammatical errors.